# Why the following program does not mix the output when mutex is not used?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have made multiple runs of the program.  I do not see that the output is incorrect, even though I do not use the mutex. My goal is to demonstrate the need of a mutex. My thinking is that different threads with different "num" values will be mixed.

Is it because the objects are different?

```
using VecI = std::vector<int>;
class UseMutexInClassMethod {
    mutex m;
public:
    VecI compute(int num, VecI veci)
    {
        VecI v;
        num = 2 * num -1;
        for (auto &x:veci) {
            v.emplace_back(pow(x,num));
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        }
        return v;
    }

};  

void TestUseMutexInClassMethodUsingAsync()
{
    const int nthreads = 5;
    UseMutexInClassMethod useMutexInClassMethod;
    VecI vec{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::vector<std::future<VecI>> futures(nthreads);
    std::vector<VecI> outputs(nthreads);

    for (decltype(futures)::size_type i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        futures[i] = std::async(&UseMutexInClassMethod::compute,
            &useMutexInClassMethod,
            i,vec
        );
    }

    for (decltype(futures)::size_type i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        outputs[i] = futures[i].get();
        for (auto& x : outputs[i])
            cout << x << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: *My goal is to demonstrate the need of mutex* -- You cannot guarantee that your output will be "messed up" by trying to force it to happen.  You will know the need for the mutex either by looking at the code and through experience, or your customers complain that your program has random crashes every other day that you've never witnessed yourself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Even with multiple runs?

Comment: Yes, even with multiple runs.  That's why MT programming is difficult -- you don't know you have a problem until the problem occurs, and that may be weeks, even months, and sometimes years after you've developed your program.  If you know by experience that you need a mutex, use a mutex, even if you can't duplicate the issue yourself.

Comment: If you could predict what the program was going to do without a mutex, then you could just assume that behavior and work with it. The whole point of mutexes is that we *can't* predict the way data races are going to happen, hence we need to take control of the situation.

Comment: In order to demonstrate you'd have to use similar mechanisms like mutexes to create a situation in which your program would be guaranteed (or at least likely enough) to mix and can only be prevented form doing so by using mutexes. Tricky, but can be done - if you know your environment even better than needed for just programming cleanly. And then explaining why the program does demonstrate and why it needs to be as complicated as that for demonstration.... I think that is a class I'd actually love to take.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. There is no shared memory (nor other shared resources) involved in your `async` calls, so why would you need any synchronization?

Comment: @DanielLangr I expect that different values of "num" will get mixed up.

Comment: num is passed by value everywhere. It can't get "mixed up"

Comment: @qqqqq Why? What matters is whether the code that is executed by `std::async` works with same (shared) memory locations. Where do you think there is any such one?

Comment: If you pass ``num`` by address then you will get messed up results but this has nothing to do with locking. https://godbolt.org/z/ceb8T58jG

Comment: @bradgonesurfing This example would be very wrong. In `compute` you are trying to access the variable `i` but this may no longer exist.

Comment: @DanielLangr I added : num = 2 * num -1; inside the method.

Comment: `num` is a local variable, passed to the function by value. All the different threads have their own copy of `num` so it's not possible for them to get messed up.

Comment: @qqqqq You didn't answer my question about where do you think you have any shared memory location inside `compute`.

Comment: @DanielLangr my point exactly. Bad things would happen if you are not careful with shared memory and threads.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You cannot guarantee that the output of any threaded program for a specific run will be incorrect. But for educational purposes it is possible to construct a program that fails more often than not if the mutex lock is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example that does fail with a high degree of certainty you can look at the below. It sets up a variable called `accumulator` to be *shared* by reference to all the futures. This is what is missing in your example. You are not actually sharing any memory. Make sure you understand the difference between [passing by reference and passing by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <mutex>


struct UseMutex{
    int compute(std::mutex & m, int & num)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0;j<1000;j++)
        {
            ///////////////////////
            // CRITICAL SECTIION //
            ///////////////////////

            // this code currently doesn't trigger the exception
            // because of the lock on the mutex. If you comment
            // out the single line below then the exception *may*
            // get called.
            std::scoped_lock lock{m};

            num++;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
            num++;
            if(num%2!=0)
                throw std::runtime_error("bad things happened");
        }

        return 0;
    }
};  

template <typename T> struct F;

void TestUseMutexInClassMethodUsingAsync()
{
  
    const int nthreads = 16;
    int accumulator=0;
    std::mutex m;
    std::vector<UseMutex> vs{nthreads};
    std::vector<std::future<int>> futures(nthreads);


    for (auto i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        futures[i]= std::async([&,i](){return vs[i].compute(m,accumulator);});
    }

    for(auto i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i){
        futures[i].get(); 
    }


}

int main(){
    TestUseMutexInClassMethodUsingAsync();
}
```

You can comment / uncomment the line

```
std::scoped_lock lock{m};
```

which protects the increment of the shared variable `num`. The rule for this mini program is that at the line

```
 if(num%2!=0)
                throw std::runtime_error("bad things happened");
```

`num` should be a multiple of two. But as multiple threads are accessing this variable without a lock you can't guarantee this. However if you add a lock around the double increment and test then you can be sure no other thread is accessing this memory during the duration of the increment and test.

Failing
https://godbolt.org/z/sojcs1WK9

Passing
https://godbolt.org/z/sGdx3x3q3

Of course the failing one is not guaranteed to fail but I've set it up so that it has a high probability of failing.

### Notes

```
[&,i](){return vs[i].compute(m,accumulator);};
```

is a lambda or inline function. The notation `[&,i]` means it captures everything by reference except `i` which it captures by value. This is important because `i` changes on each loop iteration and we want each future to get a unique value of `i`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because the objects are different?

Yes.

Your code is actually perfectly thread safe, no need for `mutex` here. You never share any state between threads except for copying `vec` from `TestUseMutexInClassMethodUsingAsync` to `compute` by `std::async` (and copying is thread-safe) and moving computation result from `compute`'s return value to `futures[i].get()`'s return value. `.get()` is also thread-safe: it blocks until the `compute()` method terminates and then returns its computation result.

It's actually nice to see that even a deliberate attempt to get a race condition failed :)

You probably have to fully redo your example to demonstrate is how simultaneous* access to a shared object breaks things. Get rid of `std::async` and `std::future`, use simple `std::thread` with capture-by-reference, remove `sleep_for` (so both threads do a lot of operations instead of one per second), significantly increase number of operations and you will get a visible race. It may look like a crash, though.

`*` - yes, I'm aware that "wall-clock simulateneous access" does not exist in multithreaded systems, strictly speaking. However, it helps getting a rough idea of where to look for visible race conditions for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Comments have called out the fact that just not protecting a critical section does not guarantee that the risked behavior actually occurs.
That also applies for multiple runs, because while you are not allowed to test a few times and then rely on the repeatedly observed behavior, it is likely that optimization mechanisms cause a likely enough reoccurring observation as to be perceived has reproducible.

If you intend to demonstrate the need for synchronization you need to employ synchronization to poise things to a near guaranteed misbehavior of observable lack of protection.

Allow me to only outline a sequence for that, with a few assumptions on scheduling mechanisms (this is based on a rather simple, single core, priority based scheduling environment I have encountered in an embedded environment I was using professionally), just to give an insight with a simplified example:

- start a lower priority context.
- optionally set up proper protection before entering the critical section
- start critical section, e.g. by outputting the first half of to-be-continuous output
- asynchronously trigger a higher priority context, which is doing that which can violate your critical section, e.g. outputs something which should not be in the middle of the two-part output of the critical section
- (in protected case the other context is not executed, in spite of being higher priority)
- (in unprotected case the other context is now executed, because  of being higher priority)
- end critical section, e.g. by outputting the second half of the to-be-continuous output
- optionally remove the protection after leaving the critical section
- (in protected case the other context is now executed, now that it is allowed)
- (in unprotected case the other context was already executed)

*Note:

I am using the term "critical section" with the meaning of a piece of code which is vulnerable to being interrupted/preempted/descheduled by another piece of code or another execution of the same code. Specifically for me a critical section can exist without applied protection, though that is not a good thing. I state this explicitly because I am aware of the term being used with the meaning "piece of code inside applied protection/synchronization". I disagree but I accept that the term is used differently and requires clarification in case of potential conflicts.*

Comment: Note that you are kind-of answering a non-existing question, since there is no critical section in OP's code.

Comment: @DanielLangr I politely disagree. A critical section is exactly what you have and even are aware of if you expect something undesired (in this case mixed output) if you do not protect/synchronise. That is what OP asks about, so they do have a critical section and are aware of or even intend to not protecting it. I assume that we agree that a critical section exists, even if you do not protect it. I mention this, because I am aware that many people understand the term differently than I do and understand "a piece of code inside a protection mechanism".

Comment: @DanielLangr I am not saying which understanding is the right/wrong one. Do you think I need an explicit definition/explanation of my understaning of the term? I would happily add one, if you think the answer would benefit from it.

Comment: But what in the observable behavior for OP's code is mixed? I don't see anything that would depend on the aspects related to threading (such as their scheduling).

Comment: I am not referring to the code, I am referring to what OP decribes as the pursued goal, to demonstrate lack of protection of a critical section - generally.

Comment: The issue of critical sections is simply demonstrated using two threads running at the same priority with a single shared integer. The overly wordy description above doesn't really help the OP get a picture of where they have gone wrong. Also there are multiple spelling mistakes with words used multiple times with different spellings.  I would suggest you also supply some code to demonstrate your *simplified example*.

Comment: I fixed your spelling mistakes for you.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Thanks for those of your edits which are fixing typos.